# Convert to 6bit

Tags: c, embedded, adc, analog-digital-converter

I am trying to tidy up this function which converts a 10bit value to 6 bit.  I also need to be able to define the bit length of the input for when I use a higher resolution ADC:

```
BYTE ioGetADC (void)                
 {
  BYTE r;

  ConvertADC();              // Start Conversion
  while(BusyADC());              // Wait for completion
   {
    r = ( (ReadADC())/16);          // Read result and convert to 0-63 (returns 10bit right hand justified)
   }

  return r;
 }
```

Comment: ADCs can set the bits either left aligned or right aligned. Little endian or big endian. Without knowing the format of the output from your ADC, nobody can answer this question.

Comment: @Lundin - the justification of bits within the word is obvious from the posted code.

Comment: @ChrisStratton No, it is not. We have no idea what `ReadADC` does. And if the code worked as expected, he wouldn't be asking a question, now would he?

Comment: @Lundin - please read the actual wording of the question.  It does not request help making the code work, but rather help "tidying it up" and making it more versatile for various input lengths.  There is only one possible alignment of the input data for which the given code is consistent with the question text.  And your question about endianness is entirely spurious as we are not accessing memory directly.

Comment: @Lundin: Whether the ADC is left or right aligned is not an issue.  If it is a 16 bit register left-aligned, you treat it as a 16 bit value, and if it is right aligned you treat it as a 10 bit value.  You are inventing problems where is are none.

Comment: ReadADC() returns a 10bit right hand justified value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on [Joachim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17445053/28169), how about:

```
uint32_t dropBits(uint32_t x, uint8_t bitsIn, uint8_t bitsOut)
{
  return x / (1 << (bitsOut - bitsIn));
}
```

so, for instance if we call `dropBits(1023, 10, 6)` to scale the maximum value of a 10-bit integer into 6 bits, it will return `1023 / (1 << 4)` which is `1023 / 16` i.e. 63, the maximum for a 6-bit value.

Of course, we can be tempted to help the compiler out since the denominator is a power of two:

```
return x >> (bitsOut - bitsIn);
```

This removes the division operator, doing it with a shift directly instead.

Note that this can only *drop* bits, it can't scale values into more bits.

Comment: The expression should be `(bitsIn - bitsOut)`.  For universality you might want to select either that or `x << (bitsOut - bitsIn)` depending on whether `bitsIn > bitsOut`, so for example you could transpose a 10 bit input to 16 bit.

Answer (score 3):

The divisor you need is the difference between the input and output bits, raised to the power of two.

Comment: Thanks.  How can I do this without <cmath>, space is a premium in my application.

Comment: Use bit shift operations rather than division!